# HP PROLIANT DL320G6 power consumption

Tags: hp

I'm cheking one colocation offer, and terms specify:

> 50 watt power consumption included, additional power usage 29,75 € cents per watt

How do I know how much will HP PROLIANT DL320G6 use power? I know that this depends on the actual server configuration (cpu, disks, memory), but in general, what can I do with 50 watts included in monthly price.

I know that G6 is specially redesigned to be power efficient (as with all G6 servers).

Hope my question did make some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50W ? well - you can power up some ethernet switch **(*)**.

G6 power calculator is [here](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/power-advisor/index.html).

(*) depends on device .

Comment: I just checked the power utilization of an old nortel 24 port 10/100 (and 1 gigabit uplink) and it uses between 35 and 50 watts.  I didn't check to see how much more power it draws with all ports active and forwarding...

Comment: @chris - right. it all depends on the switch [ and what it can do / how is it used ]. it can be below 50W or much above - hp pro curve 3400cl - 24ports, 90W max.

Answer (score 0):

One of [these](http://supermicro.com/products/system/1U/5015/SYS-5015A-H.cfm?typ=H) and a laptop drive may keep you below the 50 watt limit.   It's a supermicro 1u box with an intel atom based motherboard.  Even it has a 200W power supply, though I suspect that is twice what it needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could plug your server into a [Kill-A-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/special/P4400/P4400-CE.html) meter to determine the power consumed.

The Kill-A-Watt can display at least the following electrical characteristics (from memory):

- Amps
- Volts
- Watts
- Hertz
- Kilowatt-hours

Provided for your perusal are the [manual](http://www.p3international.com/manuals/p4400_manual.pdf) and a handy [brochure](http://www.p3international.com/brochures/P4400.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If it is 29 CENTs (not 29 Euros 75 cents per watt), that looks less outrageous than at first look if calculated through. A watt will mean 720 watt hours a month, which would probably cost you 15-20 cents in western europe if consumed at home. Now while a colo certainly gets better conditions on power, they a) get these conditions because they maintain some of their own equipment for power factor correction etc, and can give the power company quite accurate power usage forecasts (and probably commit to a certain amount of power consumed and paid each month), and b) buy and maintain all the UPS infrastructure you get to co-use...

EDIT: Also do not forget the cooling overhead.